# Make interface aware of extended base class?

Tags: php, oop, inheritance, interface, phpstorm

I have a project with a setup like this:

**Base class**

```
class MyClass extends \SplFileInfo {}
```

**Interface**

```
interface MyClassInterface {}
```

If I now typehint a method argument which contains a `MyClass` object with my `MyClassInterface` I lose the IDE completion of the \SplFileInfo object.

It seems pretty logical because the IDE only knows about the interface that is typehinted and nothing about the baseclass which extends the \SplFileInfo.

How could I program to an interface but also make my IDE aware of the baseclass's extended class? I am probably doing something wrong with the way I set up my interface but I am unsure on how to do this.

Hopefully this makes sense, otherwise let me know and I'll try to go more into detail.

Comment: It doesn't matter which class implements the interface and what methods its parent class contains. If you want to define that your interface contains methods which happen to be implemented by `SplFileInfo`, then you need to declare those methods as part of your interface.

Comment: @deceze I was afraid so.

Comment: It will be more flexible to separate SplFileInfo methods to SplFileInfoInterface.

Comment: @GermanLashevich true otherwise it will probably get quite messy. Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

Comment: You know that an interface can extend another interface? So you can do: `interface MyInterface extends SplFileInfoInterface {}`. Then you don't need to manually add all methods from SplFileInfoInterface to your own internface, but just define your own methods for MyInterface.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson true, but I would still have to make my own SplFileInfoInterface. Thanks though.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I thought that interface existed in the core. My bad.